# scrapy crawl returns nothing, the cursor just blinks

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I tried to crawl using scrapy. However I tried to replicate an online tutorial to understand the working of scrapy. But when I give the command `scrapy crawl "name"` the cursor just goes to the next line and blinks. 
I would like to know the reasons for this. What are the possible errors?

This is my code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/sfc/npo/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")
        for titles in titles:
            title=titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            link = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            print title, link
```

Comment: You should call `scrapy crawl craig` since your spider name is `"craig"`

Comment: Whatever tutorial you're using it's outdated, refer to the tutorial in the [docs](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

Comment: i used the command `scrapy crawl craig` only.but still i am not getting any response